# Which test for two groups of samples (unpaired, different size)?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I need a little help with this problem. I work in medicine and have two different groups of patients.

two groups of samples (unpaired and different size):

a= 67,4,37,91,2,3,87,2,9,3,67,38,195,0,94,1,0,3,2,3

b= 3,188,91,10,89,3,3,21,5,3,73,123,73,2,33,3,60,5,69,22,0,31,5,1,4,1,26,0,3,139,66,27,103,51,120,4,10,27,45,153,1,95

Many studies have shown, that there is significant difference between these groups of patients, or at least it should be.....but not in my tests.
I tried standard t-test, but it says there is no significant difference between groups (p=0,60), which is pretty bad for me.

I need a test which shows, that those two groups have significant difference, because I don´t know if the t-test or Welch´s test was good choice for this.

In matlab:

> > [h,p,ci,stats] = ttest2(a,b)

h =
0

p =
0.5960

ci =
-34.4264
19.9407

stats =
struct with fields:
tstat: -0.5330
df: 60
sd: 50.0214

Is the t-test (Welch's t-test) I used a good  choice? I assume the groups should have the same mean (they haven't).

Which test should I use in matlab to answer the question about significant difference? Any ideas?

Thank you a lot :)

Comment: It's not a great idea to do statistics determined to confirm or reject some prior belief:   the data says what it says, not what you want it to say. In this case, the mean of the smaller sample is a bit lower than the mean of the larger, but well within the standard error.  What sort of difference between the pools were you predicting?

Comment: Should say:  the Variance of the larger pool is so high that it's hard to imagine that you could predict much for the smaller pool.  If you are determined to reject the data as inconclusive, then the small sample size gives you cause though in that case, it was a flawed experiment from the start.   Would you have gladly accepted the data had it confirmed your prior belief?

Comment: Sorry. Tried all reasonable approaches. No significant difference. Your smaller sample `a` could almost be a subsample consisting of a randomly chosen half of observations in `b`.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. 
Any difference, I don't mind how big (or small). My prior belief was there is significant difference between them, but both of the tests show there is not. But to mention (if I understood it well)- student's t-test is for groups with the same variance ( but they have different variance)  and the Welch's test is for groups with same mean (but they have different mean) .
My question is, if there exists a test for such a groups if I don' t care of the difference and I don't have any prior belief. Would you please help me find the right test?